# Powershell Remoting: One way trust

Tags: powershell, remoting, winrm

I work at a company where the AD forest has a one-way trust with our DMZ domain (DMZ Trusts Corpnet) when attempting to run the below command from my laptop sitting on the corporate network I am not able to remote into a server sitting in our DMZ. By default `winrm quickconfig` is run on every server that is setup in the DMZ.

Is there a way to resolve this issue so i can run commands from a computer on my corporate network?

The script that was run:

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName Servername.DMZDomain.Company.com -Credential [My Creds] -ScriptBlock {get-UICulture}`

The related error that is affecting the remoting session:

> -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my issue was that i was not using FQDN in the remoting request.... I was reliying on my "DNS Suffix Search List" to autocomplete the computername which is what caused me to fail.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you get a corporate ip doesn't necessary mean that you are on the same subnet / domain.

What kind of access do you have ? You could either create a reverse ssh tunnel from DMZ machines , or using a machine that have access to the DMZ as a proxy.

Comment: I can easily access the server via remote desktop or psexec from my laptop using the same corpnet creds I just get the error when traversing the one-way trust using Enter-PSSession. A reverse SSH tunnel would probably work in this situation is not a truly viable solution as we have quarterly turnaround of the servers and would end up being more effort than it’s worth to set that up on every server every quarter.

Comment: Can you access the server via ssh ? {Propably yes}. From what you told me, my best guess is that something is wrong with PS authentication configuration (I haven't use it so i can't help you further).

By the way, what do you mean when you say that you have "quartely turnaround of the servers" ? That you change servers too often ?
If yes, do they have the same characteristics  ? In that case i suggest to use some cluster management software. You write the template once and it's automatically deployed every time you add new hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the requesting server(s) name(s) to the DMZ servers WinRM Trusted Hosts lists?

```
winrm set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="servername1,"servername2"}
```